# Get selected list items' text using class and print in span

Tags: jquery, html

### HTML

```
<ul id="specialitycenters" class="specialitycenters" name="specialty-centers">
    <li class="selected">ARCH At Risk Children Center</li>
    <li class="selected">ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS</li>
    <li class="selected">Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine</li>
    <li>After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup</li>
    <li>Allergy</li>
    <li>Allergy and Immunology</li>
    <li>Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM</li>
    <li>Anesthesiology</li>   
    <li>Comprehensive  Stone Program</li>
</ul>
```

I want to print the text of any items who have their class "selected" using jQuery. How can i do that?

I need to print the text seperated by commas.

Comment: Have you even tried? This is basic basic basic CSS selector stuff. Make an attempt before coming here please.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function.

For example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var items = '';
    $( "li.selected" ).each(function( index ) {
        items+=$(this).text()+',';
    });
    $('#specialitycenters').after('<span>'+items.slice(0,-1)+'</span>');
});
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LLaughqe/1/). Hope it helps.

Updated to include `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to select all of the lis with the "selected" class and then use the jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method to loop through them and append them wherever you need. You can use the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text from an element, as seen in the loop.

We also check whether or not we are at the last index of the loop to know whether or not to include the comma and space.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get all of the li elements with the class selected and declare
  // our text variable
  var selected = $("li.selected");
  var text;
  
  // loop over our lis and do whatever you need with them
  $.each(selected, function(index) {

    // add the comma as long as it isn't the last one in the set
    if (index === (selected.length - 1)) {
      text = $(this).text();
    } else {
      text = $(this).text() + ", "; 
    }
    
    // append the result to wherever you need, in this
    // case it would just append it to the body
    $("body").append(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="specialitycenters" class="specialitycenters" name="specialty-centers">
<li class="selected">ARCH At Risk Children Center</li>
<li class="selected">ARMS Primary care services for HIV AIDS</li>
<li class="selected">Adolescent - Young Adult Medicine</li>
<li>After the Cancer Experience ACE   Late Effects Clinic   Long Term Followup</li>
<li>Allergy</li>
<li>Allergy and Immunology</li>
<li>Analytical Imaging Modeling Center AIM</li>
<li>Anesthesiology</li>   
<li>Comprehensive  Stone Program</li>
</ul>
```